# Session-based storage of marked articels on my wordpress-page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, session

I'm creating a wordpress-website for a friend using a free theme at the moment.
I added the textual content,- mostly static wordpress-pages for each topic.

I also added a contact-form, with checkboxes for each page/topic if certain content is interesting for the user, he can check those and contact us.

My problem is, that my friend wants the user to be able to click through the page and mark intersting topics if he wants to. These topics should then be stored kind of like in an online shopping cart. And if the user is ready, he should be able to "checkout" via the contact form, with the checkboxes being checked dependent on the "shopping cart".

Sadly im stuck with this task.

What I did yet:

- searched for plugins without success
- Been thinking about e-commerce plugins, but i think i cannot manipulate to fit my needs? we dont want user-registration/login...
- Was reading about cookies/session to get an idea about them, but don't  feel ready to apply those

Are there any plugins that i could use for my problem? Or by any chance isn't it that hard programmaticaly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions:

- You can use woocommerce.
- Override its templates according to your requirement like "friend wants the user to be able to click through the page and mark interesting topics if he wants to. These topics should then be stored kind of like in an online shopping cart".
- Integrate payment method like paypal etc. Available with plugin.

If dont want to use plugin then create your own template.

- Create a .php file in root of your theme and add `<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>` on the top of file.
- implement your interesting topics in that template.
- create "cart" and "checkout" templates also
- integrate payment method like paypal.
- store records in database.
- payment completion template.